# How to get the PPI value in an AIR for iOS app?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, ppi

How to get the PPI (pixels per inch) value of an iPhone 6+ from an Air based iOS app?
I tried `Capabilities.screenDPI` but it returns the wrong value, 326 PPI instead of 401 PPI.

Comment: They don't give the actual number for that.  I forget why but that number is some standard number.  Like all desktop monitors show 72 dpi when they're much higher.

Comment: @moot si correct.  It does this with constants (rounding) and is supposedly less worrisome for us for development to use dpi scaling.  There is a way to override this behavior though... here's the doc on how to do it :)  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-2a25e9b212d622ff5e8-8000

Comment: @JasonReeves Is there something like that available for AIR too?

Comment: that is for air.  That link is specific for developing apps for mobile devices

Comment: you must try native extension for it,  because `Capabilities.screenDPI` is not a trust able value